# What is the main difference between LDA Topic Modeling in Gensim and Sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I'm not a computer scientist or an expert in Machine Learning. I was looking at topic modeling to analyse some textual data for social research. I read that Sklearn and gensim are based on the same paper (about Variational Bayes). Since if performed on the same data, they give different results, I'd like to understand in a simple and intuhitive way what are the main differences between the 2 libraries (for example, in terms of standard parameters etc.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This sort of stochastic algorithm can even give different results when re-run with the exact same library, parameters, & data. So, are the differences-between-implementations you're seeing *larger* that the differences from subsequent runs in the same implementation – for example, just with a different seed? Have you seen any results suggesting that either implementation's final results are *better* than the others, or simply of equal quality with different discovered topics/weights?